# Facebook app permission window shows only when link is opened in new tab or window

Tags: facebook, authentication, user-permissions

I am trying to create an app in facebook using Java. in my index.jsp there is a link for Favorite Sports Teams. when a user click the link the facebook supposed to ask permission from the user. But nothing works.

It works when user open link in new tab or window and the facebook permission window comes. and from next time a user click the link for Favorite Sports Teams and it works perfectly.

My question is, why for the first time the user need to open the link in new tab or window. Thank you.

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MYID&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/SimpleRestaurantSearch/nap&scope=friends_hometown,friends_likes,friends_location">Favorite Sports Teams</a>
```